# GetColumnDisplayRectangle no value if no rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-4.0

In winforms I need to retrieve the position of each column in my `DataGridView`, to do this I use this function:

```
Rectangle rec = dgv.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(getColumnIndexByName(entry.Key), true);
```

and give me the rec of the column, but if I have a table with no records, the function get a rec with 0 value...

How can I solve this??

here is what I have if the grid has rows:

[image]

in the blue panel I've got some textbox that I use as filter of the value of the column below

Now if the grid has some rows, it works perfectly, I get right the column rectangle, I obtain the left and width and I'm able to place the filters above the header.. but if I set a wrong filter and the query retrieve 0 records, I don't know where place the textboxes

Edit: the code of `getColumnIndexByName`:

```
protected int getColumnIndexByName(string name)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv.Columns)
    {
        if (col.Name.ToLower().Trim() == name.ToLower().Trim()) return col.Index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

thanks

Comment: @L.Guthardt sorry, but I've got this problem

Comment: But what do you want to receive from the table if the table is empty? And why?

Comment: the headers are still present also if I've got no rows... and I added a textbox above the header to use as filter and I need the filter always visible

Comment: Now I am more confused than before. It seems like something is working when the table contains any values, but doesnt work if the table is empty. Please update your question with more detailed information. Describe what works at the moment and when it doesnt work and what you exactly you want to get as result and what the wrong result is that you get.

Comment: How do you have an *entry.key* if you have no rows?

Comment: @user6144226the `entry.key` is the list of my filters, not the column

Comment: @L.Guthardt edited with an image.. thanks

Comment: If the column is not `Displayed` (whatever that means), the function [returns Rectangle.Empty](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,8182).

Comment: thanks @IvanStoev but not `Displayed` means also with no rows, but the header displayed.. this is my glue

Comment: Actually most likely in your case the problem is coming from the usage of `layout.Data` rectangle which I suspect is empty. You can eventually chech that with the debugger. The problem is though that I don't see a method which can be used to achieve your goal.

Comment: Please, show us code for getColumnIndexByName function

Comment: @MikkaRin edited the question with the code of the function

Answer (score 0):

`GetColumnDisplayRectangle` returns `Rectangle.Empty` if the column is not `Displayed`.

You may also want to take a look at source code for [`GetColumnDisplayRectanglePrivate`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewMethods.cs,fd3c0860ac6f7aed) method which is used by `DataGridView` to calculate rectangle of the given column.

The method contains following code:

```
if (!this.Columns[columnIndex].Displayed)
{
    return Rectangle.Empty;
}
```

**Workaround**

If you are looking for a workaround, you can use the following code which gets a list of rectangles without any flicker:

```
this.SuspendLayout();
var width = this.dataGridView1.Width;
this.dataGridView1.Width = 8388607;
var rectangles = this.dataGridView1.Columns.Cast<DataGridViewColumn>()
    .Select(x => dataGridView1.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(x.Index, false))
    .ToList();
this.dataGridView1.Width = width;
this.ResumeLayout();
```